# How to filter and fill visible cell without 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to filter column A with specified keywords then fill some text in visible cell of column B using "Sub RunThis"
Once my keyword not match with any of rows A then the error1004 appear.

Could you please suggest me to fix this ?

Thank you so much,

My cross-posting
http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=1085681&p=4088366
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=195012

```
Public LastRow As Long 
Sub RunThis() 
    LastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 
     'Suite1
     'Suite2
     'Suite3
     'Suite4
     'Suite5
    Suite6 
     'Suite7
     'Suite8
     'Suite9
     'Suite10
     'Suite11


End Sub 




 '==============================FIND===Suite6==================
Sub Suite6() 
    On Error Goto NEXT0 
     '============Search KeyWord 1 2
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _ 
    "=*S6R*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*Suite6/*" 
     ' Select target column to paste
    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Select 
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 
     ' TargetText for this search
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "Suite-6" 
NEXT0: 
    On Error Goto NEXT2 
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _ 
    "=*Suite 6/*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*Suite_6/*" 
     ' Select target column to paste
    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Select 
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 
     ' TargetText for this search
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "Suite-6" 
NEXT2: 
    On Error Goto NEXT3 
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _ 
    "=*Suite-6/*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*Suite6.*" 
     ' Select target column to paste
    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Select 
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 
     ' TargetText for this search
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "Suite-6" 
NEXT3: 
    On Error Goto NEXT4 
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _ 
    "=*Suite 6.*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*Suite_6.*" 
     ' Select target column to paste
    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Select 
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 
     ' TargetText for this search
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "Suite-6" 
NEXT4: 
    On Error Goto NEXT5 
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _ 
    "=*Suite-6.*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*Suite-6/*" 
     ' Select target column to paste
    Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Select 
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 
     ' TargetText for this search
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "Suite-6" 
NEXT5: 
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like you can use wildcards in filter expressions. I don't know how to use them but you could have a single though not simple expression like `"=*Suite[_ Or - Or vbNullString]6[. Or / Or - Or vbNullString]*"` that would cover all your cases and nothing else. This would save you some trouble with your [spaghetti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

Comment: By the way I think you have an [XY Prblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You may want to filter to [array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649275/excel-vba-autofilter-array) but don't necessarily need to. You could loop through and do the replacements without using the autofilter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your underlying issue without creating messy spaghetty code or leaving filters. As a bonus I think it will even have a lower runtime and with a bit of wits you can make it loop through suites 1-11.

```
Public LastRow As Long
Sub RunThis()
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
     'Suite1
     'Suite2
     'Suite3
     'Suite4
     'Suite5
    Suite6
     'Suite7
     'Suite8
     'Suite9
     'Suite10
     'Suite11


End Sub




 '==============================FIND===Suite6==================
Private Sub Suite6()
Dim ArrayOfStrings() As String
'ArrayOfStrings = Array("*S6R*", "*Suite6/*", "*Suite 6/*", "*Suite_6/*", "*Suite-6/*", _
                    "*Suite6.*", "*Suite 6.*", "*Suite_6.*", "*Suite-6.*", "*Suite-6/*")
ReDim ArrayOfStrings(9)
ArrayOfStrings(0) = "*S6R*"
ArrayOfStrings(1) = "*Suite6/*"
ArrayOfStrings(2) = "*Suite_6/*"
ArrayOfStrings(3) = "*Suite-6/*"
ArrayOfStrings(4) = "*Suite6.*"
ArrayOfStrings(5) = "*Suite 6.*"
ArrayOfStrings(6) = "*Suite_6.*"
ArrayOfStrings(7) = "*Suite-6.*"
ArrayOfStrings(8) = "*Suite 6/*"
ArrayOfStrings(9) = "*Suite-6/*"
ColumnToCheck = "A" 'you were looking for values in the A column, weren't you?

For i = 1 To LastRow 'in each of the rows
    For j = LBound(ArrayOfStrings) To UBound(ArrayOfStrings) 'for each of the strings it could match
        If Cells(i, ColumnToCheck).Value2 Like ArrayOfStrings(j) Then Cells(i, ColumnToCheck).Value2 = "Suite-6" 'if there's a match, then replace it with a uniform "Suite-6"
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: How to modify your code for further uses in case I don't need the number. e.g. final_data, final-data, final data, finaldata

Comment: The texts can change, feel free to add, change or delete `ArrayToStrings()` elements. If you add or substract change the `ReDim` index accordingly. `ReDim ArrayOfStrings(3) ArrayOfStrings(0) = "*final_data*" ArrayOfStrings(1) = "*final-data*" ArrayOfStrings(2) = "*final data*" ArrayOfStrings(3)= "*finaldata*"`. The other variable is the `ColumnToCheck` in case you happen to seek values in some other columns.

Comment: Could you please help me verify this code that i just changed. LINK: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DnZv3LMyy-QkxIc0c4aVQ4UEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tried your code, but it's not fill the word "Suite-6" in other column. How to fix this  ? I think your code can use will many many keyword and it should be really useful. You may edit my Excel using your code to guide me too. Thanks (I'm not Vampire :))

Comment: I see, you're trxing to modify a different Column, in this case you'll need to modify the part after the `Then`. You want to set `Cell(4,i).Value2`. I downloaded your Excel and it had nothing of my code.

Comment: I just uploaded my test using your code, but i can't see any cell get "Suite-6" applied, could you please suggest.  FileLink: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DnZv3LMyy-S0p6QzlnNHo5TFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The values are pasted to column `A`, `87974:87953` for example. Your filter doesn't seem to show the values (could have been your initial issue) but just try to find it with a built-in method. I realized I've made a mistake, change the column of the output and stop pestering me. I *have* given you the answer to the question that was only implicitly asked. If you fail to understand the basic concepts of range then try contacting a coach or consultant which I am not.